# Cannot instantiate HTMLXMLHttpRequest class from MSHTML library

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone enlighten me on how to instantiate an `HTMLXMLHttpRequest` object from the MSHTML library (Microsoft HTML Object Library)?  I'm using VBA though Excel.

I have spent hours reading the MSDN references and what other little info is available on this out there, without success.  A lot of the info I unfortunately don't understand as it pertains to JavaScript, or C++, or starts talking about various interfaces and scripting and IDispatch that i also don't understand, despite trying to read up on those also.

I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
dim httpRequest as HTMLXMLHttpRequest

set httpRequest = New HTMLXMLHttpRequest
```

but that doesn't work, `HTMLXMLHttpRequest` doesn't even show in the intellisense list after typing 'New'.

I am obviously missing/not understanding something.  Some of what I read refers to related classes `HTMLXMLHttpRequestFactory` and `IHTMLXMLHttpRequest`.

The 'create' method of the `HTMLXMLHttpRequestFactory` class returns an `IHTMLXMLHttpRequest` object, if I understand correctly.  The properties/methods of `IHTMLXMLHttpRequest` are similar to `HTMLXMLHttpRequest`, so I thought I could use that instead, and tried this:

```
dim httpRequest as IHTMLXMLHttpRequest

set httpRequest = HTMLXMLHttpRequestFactory.Create
```

But nope, doesn't work either.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim sURL As String, sHTML As String
Dim oHttp As Object

'URL to open
sURL = "http://example.com"

' Create an XMLHTTP object 
'Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")

'Open the URL 
oHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
oHttp.Send
sHTML = oHttp.responseText
```

Comment: Great - thanks @gofr1.  That does work (the MSXML2 version).  It's similar to what I was previously using: `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` though I read somewhere this is an older version or something, though still supported.  The object type created for both is`IXMLHTTPRequest`.

I can ultimately complete what I'm trying to do with this code/object, though I was hoping to understand how I might use the objects/classes within the MSHTML library directly.  Got any idea where I might find more info - or even info on ways to instantiate classes other that via dim/set/CreateObject...?

Comment: It is VBA - and it is not a modern way to make http requests :) `Dim, Set, Create` is it's syntax, you cannot get away from this :( As I know this syntax and features doesn't changed for years (some new were added). If you don't want to work with `MSXML2` directly - you can use some other tools like this: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web or write your own tool (library, project or whatever you want).

Comment: Thanks @gofr1.  I can work with MSXML2 - thanks for pointing out that object.  I just find it frustrating at times when there appear to be many useful classes in a VBA object library (MSHTML in this case), but it doesn't seem possible to use them all, and I can't find an explanation for it.  In the big picture I guess it's a minor issue, as there's usually many ways to find a workaround and get the job done regardless.  Thanks again.